# IIS8 refuses to serve up a static .wsdl file

Tags: wcf, iis, wsdl

I'm currently facing an issue I've never seen Before.
I have a static .wsdl file set in the site directory and if I navigate to the .svc file it shows up just fine, but as soon as I navigate to http://www.foo.bar/service.wsdl to download the WSDL it throws up an Error 500.0

> Module   IIS Web Core
>
> Notification   AuthenticateRequest
>
> Handler   StaticFile
>
> Error Code   0x80070542
>
> Requested URL   http://localhost/service.wsdl
>
> Physical Path   C:\sites\service.wsdl
>
> Logon Method   Anonymous
>
> Logon User   Anonymous

I know that there has been some "tuning" being made on this server, so that might be a reason, but is there a way to find out why it refuses to serve up the file?

The reason for me not going for the ?wsdl option is that the WSDL need to have some endpoints redefined due to Proxies etc.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add .WSDL to the list of file types that IIS will serve up.

Open IIS Manager, and in the root, click on MIME types.

Add `.wsdl` to the list, the type is `text/xml`.

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Hmm, just had a look at the MIME Types and .wsdl is already associated with text/xml.

Comment: In the case, might be a routing issue. If you put an HTML file into the same folder, can you access that?

Comment: Must be the way your routing is configured. Is your project part of an ASP.NET MVC application or similar? You may need to define a route.

Comment: I think I've found the root cause. The root cause being that someone at the IT operations has been tinkering with the AD user running the app pool. That user no longer has "Impersonate client after autentication" :P :P But thanks for your help SLC, it's deeply appreciated. :)